# Chrome message extension : From injected script to background

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, typescript, message

```
/* My Background */
console.log("Init BackGround ! ");
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
    (request, sender, sendResponse) => {
        console.log("J'ai bien reçu un truc");
        console.log(request);
        console.log(sender);
    }
);
    // Inject script
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener((details) => {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(details.tabId, {
        file: "include/ts/injectScript.js",
        runAt: "document_end"
    });
}, {url: [{urlPrefix: "https://website.com"}]});
console.log("End Background init");

/* My injected script */
    var extensionID = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extensionID, {test : 123},(response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });

/* One part of my manifest.json (with good url) */
"externally_connectable": {
    "matches": [
      "*://*.exemple.com/tests/*"
    ]
 },
 "permissions": [..., "*://*.exemple.com/tests/*",...]
```

The background automatically injects JS script at page load.

All tests performed in the console (on the current page) work, and the background is receiving messages.

Unfortunately, although the background well injects the script loading the page, it does not receive any messages.

Sorry for my english, 
Thank you in advance for your answers

Jérémy-F

Comment: There's no need for `extensionID` and `externally_connectable` if you communicate within your own extension. Either the question lacks relevant details or the code is needlessly overcomplicated.

Comment: @wOxxOm in my experimentation injecting a script directly into a webpage context and trying to send a message from that injected script, it always threw an error saying to specify the extensionId because the sendMessage call was no longer in the extension's context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` instead of `chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener` to receive messages from your own content scripts.

`chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal` is for messages from other extensions/apps.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It's working !!

Do you think the console is considered like external application ?

Comment: Console has a context switcher dropdown so you can use both internal and external contexts. The external contexts are all other extensions and site pages.